# Partial black screen and mouse not working

Tags: mouse, 22.04

So I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (on my Oracle virtual machine) and 3/4 of the screen is black and the mouse doesn't work on the main desktop (Where the wallpaper is- I don't know what it is called). I can click on the taskbar on the left or the power off button on the top right and when I select the "show application icon" on the bottom left the whole screen works fine and none of it is blacked out.

I don't use Ubuntu at all other than 1 app that is only available for Linux. I searched the web but couldn't find anyone with a similar problem. I appreciate any help I can get.

[3/4 of the wallpaper is blacked out and the mouse doesn't work on the wallpaper portion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RioKH.jpg)

[The entire screen is showing and the mouse works fine here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgT7R.jpg)

Comment: same problem, did you manage to find a fix ?

Comment: Install Guest Addons to the system.